# VS code html5 boilerplate red line issue

Tags: html, compiler-errors, html5boilerplate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozsZC.png)there is a red line showing in my html boilerplate VScode. this shows when I hover over it (Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)stylelint(CssSyntaxError).
Beginner level stuff I know but will be glad if someone can help

tried to google about css syntax error, re-installed vs code and used the debug option within.

UPDATE: I just uninstalled styleLint and styleLint plus extensions and the error appears to be gone

Comment: Are u using some kind of linter ? What is the language selected in your code ?

Comment: check the typing codes.check the CSS syntax and Stylelint configuration is stored in a .stylelintrc file in your project root directory. check it.

Comment: Hello!
yes, ES lint, styleLint and styLint plus extensions. selected language is HTML

Comment: Hello I haven't typed any css code yet and the error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

**Open Visual Studio Code.
Go to the Extensions view by clicking on the square icon in the sidebar or pressing Ctrl+Shift+X.
In the search bar, type "HTML" and look for an extension that provides HTML language support. One popular extension is simply called "HTML" and is provided by Visual Studio Code.
Click on the extension and then click the "Install" button.**

Comment: Hey! I just checked and an extension "HTML boilerplate" is showing already installed. 
Unable to find any extension with "HTML" name though